# This textbox works in WATIR-Webdriver but not in watir-classic

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

```
<input name="namedDriverGivenName" class="form-control ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty" id="namedDriverGivenName" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Required" data-ng-model="namedDriver.FirstName" data-ng-required="true">
```

The aforementioned text box works when I write the following code in watir-webdriver 'b.text_field(:name,'namedDriverGivenName').set 'raj' but the same code is not working in watir-classic, Can anyone please guide me what might be the problem?

EDIT

```
 <input name="mainContactPolicyholder" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" id="mainContactPolicyholder" required="required" type="text" maxlength="8" placeholder="Required" data-ng-model="phContact.PrimaryPhoneNumber" data-ng-required="true" minlength="8" data-da-hk-mobile-no="">


 <input name="emailReEnterPolicyholder" class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-email ng-dirty ng-valid-da-confirm-input" id="emailReEnterPolicyholder" required="required" type="email" placeholder="Required" data-ng-model="phContact.PrimaryEmailAddressReenter" data-ng-required="true" data-prevent-cut-copy-paste-input="" data-da-confirm-input-field-to-compare="phContact.PrimaryEmailAddress" data-da-confirm-input="">
```

puts b.text_field(:id,'mainContactPolicyholder').exists? => true

puts b.text_field(:id,'emailReEnterPolicyholder').exists? => false

The above two text boxes exist in my page, but first one give the result true and the second one gives the result false, but when I use Watir-Webdriver it recognizes both the text boxes correctly, Why it is the case?

Comment: Can you please give me more specific about what not working in Watir-Classic means? Is there an exception? When I tried a page with just that HTML, it was inputted successfully.

Comment: I updated my code, Can you please check it now? One text box is being recognized by the code and another is not even being recognized by the code, but when I use watir-webdriver, it recognizes both the text boxes correctly and enter the value, why it is the case?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an old version of Watir-Classic. Using `input` elements of type "email" was fixed in v4.1.0.

Comment: I am using watir-classic 3.7.0, I haven't upgraded because the versions which comes after that speed is very slow.

Comment: I upgraded to watir-classic version 4.1.0 but it throws this error 'Error: IDITHarnessTest: SystemStackError: stack level too deep' Can you please guide me how to overcome this problem? I am using watir 4.0.2

Comment: hi Thanks, You are correct, the higher version works perfectly. but only problem is, it is very slow while it's entering the text inside the text box compared to watir-classic 3.7.0

Comment: If you can create an example that reproduces the performance issue, you should log an issue to the project.

Comment: Hi Justin Ko, I have noticed that higher version slow speed is intentional, they have given sleeping second 0.08 between the character entry, If I removed that it works fine, So it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is not to use Watir classic. We'll be updating the documentation soon to indicate its status as a deprecated project. Focus on getting your tests to work with Watir webdriver.

Comment: Webdriver is missing some important facilities which watir-classic has. But watir-webdriver doesn't have attach function like watir-classic has, watir::Browser.attach(:index,0).

Comment: hi I have updated the question, Can you please answer to my question now?

Comment: My answer is completely legitimate to your question. We no longer support Watir-classic; update to the latest technology, where, as you pointed out, it does in fact work. :)

Comment: "Webdriver is missing some important facilities which watir-classic has."  Can you provide examples?  And watir-webdriver allows "attaching" via [window-switching](https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/window_switching_spec.rb).

Comment: orde, watir-classic provides a way to open a browser independently of watir, and then attach a watir session to it. Watir-webdriver right now will only list windows that were created by the code in the first place. The maintainer of the IEDriver suggested that it might be possible to add this feature to webdriver, but that it didn't appear to be a feature that most people were interested in. Either way, the IEDriver will eventually be deprecated by Microsoft's WebDriver implementation for Edge
For requesting selenium features: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues

Comment: titusfortner: thx for the info.  I vaguely remember that behavior, but I've been all watir-webdriver all-the-time for a while now.  I agree with you: "Focus on getting your tests to work with Watir webdriver."

Comment: orde The following code can't be possible in Watir-webdriver

b=Watir::Browser.attach(:index,0)

Comment: titusfortner I have used IEDriver, but it can't even compared to watir-classic, there are many problem I am facing while I was using that which completely absent while I use watir-classic.

Comment: RAJ - If you start with ```b=Watir::Browser.new``` before you start doing things in the browser manually, you'll still be able to drive the browser whenever you need to. You are welcome to continue using the older versions of the code, just don't expect it to always work, or expect people to provide you support for it.